# How to write join query in nodejs server loopback?

Tags: node.js, nodejs-server

How to write join query in nodejs server loopback? Because I want to fetch data according to condition on second table's field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use the `include` filter in LoopBack.

The Official Document is here:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Include-filter.html

PS: You can also refer to this answer:
[Make a join query in loopback.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231795/make-a-join-query-in-loopback-io)

Good day  ͡⚆ ͜ʖ ͡⚆