# Join on two columns in loopback

Tags: mysql, loopbackjs

I have an table `item` with columns `id survey name response` where `id` is primary.

And a dictionary table `survey name description` where `survey+name` is unique. I want to create a model for the following SQL join in loopback 3:

```
SELECT i.survey, i.name, i.response, d.description
FROM  item i
LEFT JOIN  dictionary d ON d.survey = i.survey AND d.name = i.name
```

I have not been able to find a reference how to create a join on two columns.  All examples I found in the documentation of [`loopback`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-models.html) and on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231795/make-a-join-query-in-loopback-io) only refer to joins on one primary/foreign key.